# Cooling fan problem on Acer Nitro 5

Tags: dual-boot, acer, overheating, fan

I am using an [Acer Nitro 5](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/NH.Q2QEK.002) with dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. The cooling fan works great while on Windows but the laptop overheats when working on Ubuntu, with no sound of the fan working. I have tried some of the solutions mentioned on this website to no avail. I have the latest Intel microcode installed. Can anyone provide a step by step guide to solve this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 [near end of July](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS). My fan works on my Acer Nitro 5 (AN515-53).